# Java Class "BCRSAPublicKey" Intermittently Not Found

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pgp, knime

**Context**

- Using KNIME 4.1.2, Windows 10, x64, JDK 1.8, Java Edit Snippet
- I am attempting to use the Java Snippet to read a CSV file, pgp encrypt it using a public key, and save the resulting file to a temporary folder
- I have been attempting to use BounceCastle Library v1.65

```
        try {
        encryptFile(    
                  "encryptedfile.csv.pgp",
                  "original.csv",
                  "/key/pub.asc",
                  false,
                  false);
       } catch(Exception e) {
        out_result = "fail";
       }
```

The challenge is, I get the following error in the console INTERMITTENTLY and I am unclear what I am incorrectly providing to the library / not including. The confounding is because it is intermittent and sometimes yields the properly encrypted file.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/asymmetric/rsa/BCRSAPublicKey
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.KeyFactorySpi.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:328)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaPGPKeyConverter.implGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaPGPKeyConverter.getPublicKey(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator.encryptSessionInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.PublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator.generate(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedDataGenerator.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedDataGenerator.open(Unknown Source)
    at JSnippet.encryptFile(JSnippet.java:144)
    at JSnippet.encryptFile(JSnippet.java:107)
    at JSnippet.snippet(JSnippet.java:174)
    at org.knime.base.node.jsnippet.JavaSnippetCellFactory.getCells(JavaSnippetCellFactory.java:300)
```